# What is the interpretation of a value of a node in Random Forest Regressor's Decision Tree (Python)?

Tags: python, random-forest

I'm currently working on an algorithm to improve the "feature_importances_" attribute in Random Forest Regressor, since it can potentially be misleading because of the presence "...of high-cardinality features."
Nevertheless, I've been reading *Classification and Regression Trees (Breiman et al., 1984)*, *Random Forests (Breiman, 2001)* and sklearn's documentation for regression trees, but I haven't found any mention of the meaning/interpretation of the "value" attribute of a node within a decision tree. I provided an image for clarification.

Could someone explain what the "value" attribute mean for the root node[Rahmstorf Sealevel/ Temperature model via RF Regressor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O03EN.png)

I've been researching Random Forest Regressor for my thesis and haven't found any mention of it, besides its interpretation for classifications problems.

Comment: @NickODell Okay, so my understanding is that the value of a node is the average of the target variable that corresponds to a predictor that falls within a range of values? Or is the average of the predictor itself (e.g., the average of  of all values x1<= 2)?

Comment: @NickODell It's the average of the prediction. Sorry, I misread that. Thanks

Comment: Another way of thinking of it is, "If I stopped at this node in the tree and didn't go further, what would my best guess for the dependent variable be?"